# Can I constrain the owl:onProperties when traversing over owl:Restrictions?

Tags: sparql, owl, graphdb

I'd like to use ChEBI to determine which molecular entities could be considered "[taxanes](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/chebi/searchId.do?chebiId=CHEBI:36064)", in the informal language that physicians use.

The [Anatomical and Therapeutic Classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatomical_Therapeutic_Chemical_Classification_System) places both docetaxel and paclitaxel in class [L01CD](https://mor.nlm.nih.gov/RxClass/search?query=Taxanes%7CATC1-4&searchBy=class&sourceIds=&drugSources=atc1-4%7Catc%2Cepc%7Cdailymed%2Cmeshpa%7Cmesh%2Cdisease%7Cmedrt%2Cchem%7Cdailymed%2Cmoa%7Cdailymed%2Cpe%7Cdailymed%2Cpk%7Cmedrt%2Ctc%7Cfmtsme%2Cva%7Cva%2Cdispos%7Csnomedct%2Cstruct%7Csnomedct%2Cschedule%7Crxnorm#) "Taxanes", but in ChEBI the paths include both subclass relations and
`'has parent hydride' some 'taxane'` relations, from an OWL perspective. The following SPARQL finds both docetaxel and paclitaxel

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
select * where { 
    ?drug (rdfs:subClassOf|owl:someValuesFrom)*
        <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/CHEBI_36064> .
    optional {
        ?drug rdfs:label ?l .
    }
} 
order by ?l
```

I'm not explicitly requiring here that the `owl:someValuesFrom` predicate is applied to an `owl:Restiction` in the `rdfs:subClassOf` path. **How could I limit this query so that only certain `owl:onProperty`s (like 'has parent hydride') are allowed in combination with that implicit `owl:Restriction`?**

I'm afraid that this query is dangerously under specified as it is.

Comment: Do you mean something like: `?x rdfs:subClassOf [ owl:onProperty <aCertainProperty>; owl:someValuesFrom ?y ] .` but where the someValueFrom could be a nesting of restrictions that eventually ends with `:CHEBI_36064`?

Comment: @AntoineZimmermann that sounds right. I know that the ChEBI paths from docetaxel or paclitaxel to taxane just include`rdfs:subClassOf` and `owl:someValuesFrom` relations. I would like to generalize that pattern (and possibly traverse `owl:intersection`s as well.) I'm confident that the attributes of taxanes are transitive over 'has parent hydride' `owl:onProperty` restrictions, but I would like to filter or at least report all other `owl:onProperty`s that could be nested/chained together. There are probably `owl:onProperty`s over which the taxane properties wouldn't be inherited.